# Concatenate only lines matching strings

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have
file 1

```
C2
H1
H2
H3
H4
L1
L10
L2
L3
L4
```

and file 2

```
/C2/C2_CRRA200017850-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/H1/H1_CRRA200017885-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/H1/H1_CRRA200017885-1a_H5MLCDSXY_L1
/H2/H2_CRRA200017886-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/H3/H3_CRRA200017887-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/H4/H4_CRRA200017888-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L1/L1_CRRA200017897-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L2/L2_CRRA200017898-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L3/L3_CRRA200017899-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L4/L4_CRRA200017900-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L4/L4_CRRA200017900-1a_H5MLCDSXY_L1
```

I need to produce an output where, If multiple lines in file 2 match strings in file 1 then concatenate them, otherwise print single line.

```
/C2/C2_CRRA200017850-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/H1/H1_CRRA200017885-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1 /H1/H1_CRRA200017885-1a_H5MLCDSXY_L1
/H2/H2_CRRA200017886-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/H3/H3_CRRA200017887-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/H4/H4_CRRA200017888-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L1/L1_CRRA200017897-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L2/L2_CRRA200017898-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L3/L3_CRRA200017899-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L4/L4_CRRA200017900-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1 /L4/L4_CRRA200017900-1a_H5MLCDSXY_L1
```

Another way of thinking is if lines in file 2 have the same string at /*/* then concatenate them, otherwise print single line.

Have tried several grep cmd but none worked.

Comment: can you verify ... for the first entry from `file 2` ... the **only** string used for comparison purposes is `/C2/`? you don't care about the matching `C2` in `C2_CRRA...`? and you don't need to match `L1` from the end of the line (`...SXY_L1`)? And if you have an entry in `file 2` that does not have a match from `file 1` (eg, `file 2` == `/D3/D3_..._L1`) then this row does **not** show up in the output?

Comment: is `file 2` already sorted as displayed, with all matching lines listed next to each other?

Comment: You've asked and received answers to a ton of awk questions over the past year or 2, you must have SOME attempt to do this yourself that you can add to your question so we can help you with  that. Without code this question is asking to be closed since the forum exists to help people with their code, not to write code for people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might first store all the values of file1 in an array `ary`.

Then create a mapper where the key between the first `//` is present in ary, and concat for the value the lines separated by a space.

The count will increate by 1 for every new entry in mapper, and is used when printing in the resulting array to keep the order.

In the END block you can print the values of the result array.

```
awk -v FS="/" '
FNR==NR{
  ary[$0];next
}
{
  if($2 in ary){
    if(mapper[$2]) {
      mapper[$2] = mapper[$2] " " $0
      next
    }
    mapper[$2] = $0;
    result[++count] = $2    
    next
  }
  result[++count] = $0
}
END {
  for (line = 1; line <= count; line++) {
    print result[line] in mapper ? mapper[result[line]] : result[line]
  }
}
' file1 file2
```

Example file2

```
/L1/L1_CRRA200017897-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/C2/C2_CRRA200017850-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/H1/H1_CRRA200017885-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/H1/H1_CRRA200017885-1a_H5MLCDSXY_L1
/H2/H2_CRRA200017886-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/H3/H3_CRRA200017887-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/H4/H4_CRRA200017888-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L1/L1_CRRA200017897-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L2/L2_CRRA200017898-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L3/L3_CRRA200017899-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L4/L4_CRRA200017900-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L4/L4_CRRA200017900-1a_H5MLCDSXY_L1
/X9/X9_CRRA200017900-1c_H5MLCDSXY_L1
/X9/X9_CRRA200017900-1c_H5MLCDSXY_L1
/L4/L4_CRRA200017900-1a_H5MLCDSXY_L1
/X8/X8_CRRA200017900-1b_H5MLCDSXY_L1
/X9/X9_CRRA200017900-1c_H5MLCDSXY_L1
```

Output

```
/L1/L1_CRRA200017897-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1 /L1/L1_CRRA200017897-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/C2/C2_CRRA200017850-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/H1/H1_CRRA200017885-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1 /H1/H1_CRRA200017885-1a_H5MLCDSXY_L1
/H2/H2_CRRA200017886-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/H3/H3_CRRA200017887-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/H4/H4_CRRA200017888-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L2/L2_CRRA200017898-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L3/L3_CRRA200017899-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L4/L4_CRRA200017900-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1 /L4/L4_CRRA200017900-1a_H5MLCDSXY_L1 /L4/L4_CRRA200017900-1a_H5MLCDSXY_L1
/X9/X9_CRRA200017900-1c_H5MLCDSXY_L1
/X9/X9_CRRA200017900-1c_H5MLCDSXY_L1
/X8/X8_CRRA200017900-1b_H5MLCDSXY_L1
/X9/X9_CRRA200017900-1c_H5MLCDSXY_L1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
/C2/C2_CRRA200017850-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/H1/H1_CRRA200017885-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/H1/H1_CRRA200017885-1a_H5MLCDSXY_L1
/H2/H2_CRRA200017886-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/H3/H3_CRRA200017887-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/H4/H4_CRRA200017888-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L1/L1_CRRA200017897-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L2/L2_CRRA200017898-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L3/L3_CRRA200017899-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L4/L4_CRRA200017900-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L4/L4_CRRA200017900-1a_H5MLCDSXY_L1
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="/";ORS=""}NR>=2{print (prev!=$2)?"\n":" "}{print;prev=$2}' file.txt
```

output

```
/C2/C2_CRRA200017850-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/H1/H1_CRRA200017885-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1 /H1/H1_CRRA200017885-1a_H5MLCDSXY_L1
/H2/H2_CRRA200017886-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/H3/H3_CRRA200017887-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/H4/H4_CRRA200017888-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L1/L1_CRRA200017897-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L2/L2_CRRA200017898-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L3/L3_CRRA200017899-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1
/L4/L4_CRRA200017900-1a_H3LJWDSXY_L1 /L4/L4_CRRA200017900-1a_H5MLCDSXY_L1
```

Explanation: I set *field seperator* (`FS`) to `/`, I do use 2nd column for comparison as 1st column is empty (there is nothing before 1st `/` in each line). I set *output row seperator* (`ORS`) to empty string, as I will provide newlines and spaces myself. For every line I `print` current line and set `prev` variable to content of 2nd column, thus it is indeed *previous* value when working with newline. For 2nd and following rows (i.e. with *number row* (`NR`) greater or equal 2), before printing line I either put newline `\n` if previous value of $2 was different else space  , in order to do so I harness AWK ternary operation, i.e. condition`?`valueiftrue`:`valueiffalse. If you want to know more about built-in variables used read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's#.*#/^\\/&\\//ba#' file1 |
sed -f - -Ee 'b;:a;N;/^\/([^\/]*)\/.*\n.\1/s/\n/ /;ta;P;D' file2
```

Use file1 to build sed commands to match in file2, if the literal in file1 matches the first literal in file2, jump to a place in the second sed invocation to try and merge the following line(s).

The second invocation of sed uses the ouput from file1 to match and if it does not it bails out.

If the match is true, append the following line and if that line matches too, remove the newline separating the two lines and repeat.

Otherwise, print the first of the two lines in the pattern space (the possible merged line), delete it and repeat.

N.B. The `D` command suppresses the automatic reading in of the next line if the pattern space is not empty.